# How to detect SerialDataReceivedEvent Args when while loop is still ongoing?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, barcode-scanner

I created a program combining scanner (using comport) and weight, and I want to escape a while loop when another data is received from SerialDataReceivedEventArgs.

I have write this code to handle the data:

```
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
  { 
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        dataScanned = sp.ReadLine();
        dataScanned = dataScanned.Trim();
  }
```

How to detect when another Scan is being done?

Edit:

As mentioned by @Ozgur Saklanmaz I want the DataReceived interrupt to be triggered if new data is triggered, delete the previous data and process the new data immediately.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: This is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - a while loop waiting for user input is the wrong way in wpf

Comment: If you explain in detail what you really want to do, it may be more helpful. Do you want the DataReceived interrupt to be triggered if new data is triggered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @OzgurSaklanmaz, yes that exactly what I want, however until now I have not found the solution or reference on how to do that.

Comment: I am using a method like this to process the data; I write every incoming data to a list without any action. In this way, the interrupt is not busy. I make sense of this data according to my request (protocol) in a different timer. You can try this method.